# draw non intersecting straight line paths in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a system where different users will draw their desired straight line paths in google map. For simplicity I have restricted user to draw only straight line paths.
I am saving starting and ending points latitude and longitudes in the database.
The system should detect whether the current given path intersects with any of the previously submitted paths or not.
Any suggestion how to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be nice to say what you've tried and how are you drawing the lines

Comment: using google map drawing tool to draw the lines and saving their starting and ending point coordinates in database.

Comment: Do some research into detecting intersecting lines based on start/end coordinates. More of a math issue than map one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

- If your data is stored in a spatial database such as SQL, there are spatial math tools already built in. Simply do an intersection test in your database. Here is some documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stintersects-geography-data-type
- If you have the data client side (in the browser), you can perform the calculation there. Google maps doesn't provide any real spatial math calculations, so you would have to look around for an algorithm. Alternatively, take a look at Bing Maps, it has a spatial math library with a ton of calculations, including an intersects function. Here are some samples and resources:

http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Binary%20Operations

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt762861.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Atleast I got an idea how to proceed. Thank you very much!